# Verify email address using AD B2C?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I have a section of our site where a user can edit the email address they use to sign in. I think it would be a good idea to also have the user enter a verification code to ensure that the email address they entered is not only correct, but also just generally valid.

I know B2C allows me to issue a Graph API request that will modify the `identities` property with a patch request as such:

```
{
    "identities":  [
        {
            "signInType": "emailAddress",
            "issuer": "contoso.onmicrosoft.com",
            "issuerAssignedId": "newemail@email.com"
        }
    ]
}
```

And this generally works to detect conflicting emails and so on. But is it possible to programmatically trigger B2C to send out a verification email or does such an infrastructure have to be built out by us?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to do email verification is through a Azure AD B2C User Flow or Custom Policy.
You can see how this works in the [Sign In/Up User Flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-create-user-flows).

AAD B2C service does not expose an API endpoint to send out a verification code.

Comment: is it possible to run this flow via api calls? I know its possible to create an account via api, but in that case its not verified if the user owns the e-mail address.

Comment: It is not possible.