# Account or email verification during sign up for users in Azure AD using Microsoft graph API's

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c

Our scenario: Verify the email address of the users created in Azure AD during signup process where user is expected to receive a verification mail to his mail id upon creating a account. And when user clicks on the link, user's email address should be verified. This should be achieved through REST API's.

Are there any Microsoft graph API's which handles above scenario?

Comment: Why don't you use the "Verified.Email" construct? This pretty much does what you want.

Answer (score 0):

> **Note** that: There is no direct API endpoint/Microsoft Graph API endpoint to verify the email address. You have to either user Azure AD B2C user flows or Custom policies to verify the email address.

In **Azure AD B2C custom policy,** you can add the email verification to the email output claim by adding `PartnerClaimType="Verified.Email"`  to the self-asserted technical profile like below:

```xml
<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="Verified.Email" Required="true" />
```

I created an Azure AD User flow with page layout version:

[image]

When I run the user flow and used an **invalid email address to sign-up**, I got the error like below:

[image]

**Otherwise**, you can customize the user flow or the error messages in Azure AD B2C flow. Refer this [**MsDoc**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/customize-ui-with-html?pivots=b2c-user-flow).

**References:**

[Is there a way to force email verification in Azure B2C? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71473820/is-there-a-way-to-force-email-verification-in-azure-b2c-before-allowing-user-to) by KavyaS

[azure ad b2c - Verify email address using AD B2C? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64382902/verify-email-address-using-ad-b2c) by Jas Suri - MSFT